# DataGridview calculation

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Datagridview with attached columns and want to perform following tasks:

> Once the value of "Quantity", "unit price" and GST is filled. The total should be calculated using formula
>
> ```
> (Quantity*Unit price) * GST Percentage
> ```

And:

> Once total is filled, the grand total value needs to be calculated based on cell value filled.

Let me know if you have any questions.

[image]

Tried following code but its not working:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex.Equals(4) && e.ColumnIndex.Equals(5) && e.ColumnIndex.Equals(8))
        {
            double total = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1["UnitPrice", e.RowIndex].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1["Quantity", e.RowIndex].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1["GST", e.RowIndex].Value);
            dataGridView1["Total", e.RowIndex].Value = total.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: As a matter of preference, I like using `==` over `.Equals()`, personally I think it is easier to read (it is not related to your question, just an advice). Check [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73522244/2265446), it could solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This expression is always `false` because `e.ColumnIndex` cannot be equal to 4, 5 and 8 at the same time:

```
e.ColumnIndex.Equals(4) && e.ColumnIndex.Equals(5) && e.ColumnIndex.Equals(8)
```

Use `||` ([conditional logical OR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-)) instead:

```
e.ColumnIndex.Equals(4) || e.ColumnIndex.Equals(5) || e.ColumnIndex.Equals(8)
```